# For/Foreach loop stops at first conditoin and never resumes

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

A Have an `array` like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3035
            [category] => Preliminary
            [value] => 0
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202924
            [remarks] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3035
            [category] => Midterm
            [value] => 0
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202924
            [remarks] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3035
            [category] => Semi-Finals
            [value] => 0
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202924
            [remarks] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3035
            [category] => Finals
            [value] => 0
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202924
            [remarks] => 
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3035
            [category] => Remedial
            [value] => 0
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202924
            [remarks] => 
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3036
            [category] => Preliminary
            [value] => 0
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202925
            [remarks] => 
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3036
            [category] => Midterm
            [value] => 0
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202925
            [remarks] => 
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3036
            [category] => Semi-Finals
            [value] => 0
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202925
            [remarks] => 
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3036
            [category] => Finals
            [value] => 0
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202925
            [remarks] => 
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3036
            [category] => Remedial
            [value] => 0
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202925
            [remarks] => 
        )
```

i would like to format it like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => 
            [studid] => 1202924
            [user_id] => 3035
            [Preliminary] => 0
            [Midterm] => 0
            [Semi-Finals] => 0
            [Finals] => 0
            [Remedial] => 0
        ),
    [1] => array
         (
            [fullname] =>
            [studid] => 1202925
            [user_id] => 3036
            [preliminary] => 0
            [midterm] => 0
            [semi-finals] => 0
            [finals] => 0
            [remedial] => 0
         )
)
```

basically grouping them by their `studid` or `user_id`

now i tried many attempts like

```
$count = 0;
$uid = $subject_student_grades[$count]->user_id;

for($x=0;$x < count($subject_student_grades);$x++)
{
    if($uid == $subject_student_grades[$x]->user_id)
    {
        $test[$count]['fullname'] = $subject_student_grades[$x]->fullname;
        $test[$count]['studid'] = $subject_student_grades[$x]->studid; 
        $test[$count]['user_id'] = $subject_student_grades[$x]->user_id; 
        $test[$count][$subject_student_grades[$x]->category] =      $subject_student_grades[$x]->value;
    }else{
        $count++;
    }
 }
```

**AND**

$count = 0;
    foreach($subject_student_grades as $value)
    {

```
    $uid = $subject_student_grades[$count]->user_id;

    if($uid == $value->user_id)
    {
        $test[$count]['fullname'] = $value->fullname;
        $test[$count]['studid'] = $value->studid; 
        $test[$count]['user_id'] = $value->user_id; 
        $test[$count][$value->category] = $value->value;

    }else{
        $count++;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that it loops only the first part the one with the `0` index and after the condition it stops and does not process or loops on the rest, care to point out what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**
So now i edited it and placed the count outside the `foreach loop` still the same only iterates on first `array` i think after the condition it is not resuming? if i remove the `else{}` it outputs a different array structure much worst than what i am aiming.

I tried to `echo` out something on the else and it `echo's` it i think the problem here is that after the loop went on the condition it returns true and after that goes on to else and does not come back to the `if clause`.

Comment: Are you by chance trying to get rid of objects generated by `json_decode()`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario this are data from database returned as object

Comment: @tomexsans I think you should rather reshape your SQL query then. A better query means less coding, less load, happy customers, and so on...

Comment: @ppeterka the sad part is that this is the best query if tried all approach, the db structure is not that good and i'm justnew here

Answer (score 1):

There is one error for sure in there, regarding `$count` in the second loop:

```
foreach($subject_student_grades as $value)
{
    $count = 0; //Why is that here?
```

This way, each iteration will overwrite the `$count` to `0`, so the `$test` array is always addressed with `0`, so element `0` will be the only one in there.

This should read like:

```
$count = 0;

foreach($subject_student_grades as $value)
{
    $uid = $subject_student_grades[$count]->user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Count must be outside the loop:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($subject_student_grades as $value)
{
    $uid = $subject_student_grades[$count]->user_id;

    if($uid == $value->user_id)
    {
        $test[$count]['fullname'] = $value->fullname;
        $test[$count]['studid'] = $value->studid; 
        $test[$count]['user_id'] = $value->user_id; 
        $test[$count][$value->category] = $value->value;

    }

    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of a foreach is so you don't really need to maintain a count except for perhaps building a new array (however there is shorthand you can use).

I would just do this

```
$test = array();
foreach($subject_student_grades as $value) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp['fullname'] = $value->fullname;
    $temp['studid'] = $value->studid; 
    $temp['user_id'] = $value->user_id; 
    $temp[$value->category] = $value->value;

    $test[] = $temp; # This is shorthand to assign the next numerical index

}
```

The if statement seemed redundant and because it prevented count++ when true your loop will get completely out of sync as the foreach automatically moves ahead while your count would not the first time and so will always be one out